# Is there a way to copy the date based on another column date in dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to display the end date to the previous start date only but I have no idea how to do it. If I use `bfill()` and only remove the value if there is no existing value at start date, it will be not efficient and quite troublesome.

| Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/2023 22:00 | 01/02/2023 05:00 |  |
| 01/02/2023 23:00 |  |  |
| 02/02/2023 00:00 |  | 02/02/2023 00:00 |
| 02/02/2023 01:00 | 02/02/2023 01:00 |  |
| 02/02/2023 02:00 |  |  |
| 02/02/2023 03:00 |  | 02/02/2023 03:00 |

...

So, it will look like this. Is there anyone can enlighten me the method.

| Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/02/2023 22:00 | 01/02/2023 05:00 | 02/02/2023 00:00 |
| 01/02/2023 23:00 |  |  |
| 02/02/2023 00:00 |  | 02/02/2023 00:00 |
| 02/02/2023 01:00 | 02/02/2023 01:00 | 02/02/2023 03:00 |
| 02/02/2023 02:00 |  |  |
| 02/02/2023 03:00 |  | 02/02/2023 03:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": [
            "01/02/2023 22:00",
            "01/02/2023 23:00",
            "02/02/2023 00:00",
            "02/02/2023 01:00",
            "02/02/2023 02:00",
            "02/02/2023 03:00",
        ],
        "Start": ["01/02/2023 05:00", "", "", "02/02/2023 01:00", "", ""],
        "End": ["", "", "02/02/2023 00:00", "", "", "02/02/2023 03:00"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```py
df = df.replace("", pd.NA)
df.loc[~(df["Start"].isna() & df["End"].isna()), "End"] = df.loc[
    ~(df["Start"].isna() & df["End"].isna()), "End"
].fillna(method="bfill")
```

Then:

```py
               Date             Start               End
0  01/02/2023 22:00  01/02/2023 05:00  02/02/2023 00:00
1  01/02/2023 23:00              <NA>              <NA>
2  02/02/2023 00:00              <NA>  02/02/2023 00:00
3  02/02/2023 01:00  02/02/2023 01:00  02/02/2023 03:00
4  02/02/2023 02:00              <NA>              <NA>
5  02/02/2023 03:00              <NA>  02/02/2023 03:00
```

**EXTENDED ANSWER**

Now, if you don't want to retain the values in "End" column that were used to update the target rows (which is not what you posted as expected output), here is one way to proceed:

```py
df = df.replace("", pd.NA)

# Identify source rows index and save it for later use
sliced = df.loc[~(df["Start"].isna() & df["End"].isna()), "End"]
mask = sliced[~sliced.isna()].index

# Update target values
df.loc[~(df["Start"].isna() & df["End"].isna()), "End"] = df.loc[
    ~(df["Start"].isna() & df["End"].isna()), "End"
].fillna(method="bfill")

# Empty source values
df.loc[mask, "End"] = pd.NA
```

Then:

```py
               Date             Start               End
0  01/02/2023 22:00  01/02/2023 05:00  02/02/2023 00:00
1  01/02/2023 23:00              <NA>              <NA>
2  02/02/2023 00:00              <NA>              <NA>
3  02/02/2023 01:00  02/02/2023 01:00  02/02/2023 03:00
4  02/02/2023 02:00              <NA>              <NA>
5  02/02/2023 03:00              <NA>              <NA>
```

Comment: thank you so much! but what if I only want keep the updated date of the 'end' column? means that the original date from the 'end' column will be NaN.

Comment: HI, I've updated my answer to deal with your question as I understand it. Cheers.